# if a user enters a fraction as one of the values of the matrix that it will simply convert to float

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to fill in a matrix, and at the same time if a for example "1/7" get entered that it converts to float ? but it doesn't work

```
import fractions
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from fractions import Fraction
from tkinter.font import Font
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import sqlite3
import tkinter.messagebox
import os
import sys
```

#this function contain a small window that you need to put the number of criteria in  ,which will be the dimension of the  maTRIX , WHEN I FILL THE matrix and click submit for it to be saved it doesn't work
def be():
window = Tk()

```
    window.title("Dimensions ")
    window.geometry("300x200")

    def variable():
        global fn, f
        fn = entry_1.get()
        f = entry_2.get()

    ln = StringVar()
    df = []

    name = StringVar()

    def save():
        for entries in range(len(df)):
            df[entries] = name.get()

    for entries in range(len(df)):
        df = df.append({'Critere': df[entries].get()}, ignore_index=True)
    print(df)
    df

    def open_window():
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry("460x600")
        root.title('AHP Application ')
        # global f
        # f=printent()
        # print(f)
        for i in range(int(f)):
            # c = input("Enter valeur {}: ".format(i))

            my_label = Label(root, text="Entrer le critere numero 0{} :".format(i + 1), width=24, font=("bold", 10))
            my_label.grid(row=i, column=0, pady=20, padx=5)

            my_entry = Entry(root)
            my_entry.grid(row=i, column=1, pady=20, padx=5)
            df.append(my_entry)

        suivant1 = tk.Button(root, text="Suivant", width=8, borderwidth=3, command=hope).place(x=370, y=40)
  
        fermer2 = tk.Button(root, text="Fermer", width=8, borderwidth=3).place(x=370, y=90)
        root.mainloop()

    label_1 = Label(window, text="Entrer L'Objectif de Votre projet :", width=24, font=("bold", 10))
    label_1.place(x=3, y=0)

    entry_1 = Entry(window)

    entry_1.place(x=100, y=30)

    label_2 = Label(window, text="Entrer le nombre de critère :", width=20, font=("bold", 10))
    label_2.place(x=3, y=70)

    entry_2 = Entry(window)

    # Remove default 0
    entry_2.delete(0, END)
    entry_2.place(x=100, y=100)

    suivant = tk.Button(window, text="suivant", borderwidth=3, command=lambda: [variable(), open_window()]).place(x=40,
                                                                                                                  y=150)

    fermer = tk.Button(window, text="fermer", borderwidth=3).place(x=190, y=150)

    def hope():
        win = Tk()
        win.title("Matrix")
        win.geometry("700x500")
        global f

        print(f)

        wrapper1 = LabelFrame(win, text="Enter matrix")

        wrapper3 = LabelFrame(win, text="Resultats")

        wrapper1.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=50, pady=20)

        wrapper3.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=20, pady=10)

        def convert_to_float(frac_str):
            try:
                return float(frac_str)
            except ValueError:
                num, denom = frac_str.split('/')
                try:
                    leading, num = num.split(' ')
                    whole = float(leading)
                except ValueError:
                    whole = 0
                frac = float(num) / float(denom)
                return whole - frac if whole < 0 else whole + frac

   # empty arrays for your Entrys and StringVars
        text_var = []
        entries = []
        matrix = []

        # callback function to get your StringVars
        def get_mat():
            for i in range(rows):
                matrix.append([])
                for j in range(cols):
                    matrix[i].append(convert_to_float (text_var[i][j].get()))
            print(matrix)
            b = np.array(matrix, dtype=float, order='C')
            print(b)

            global df2, df, c
            index = []
            columns = []
            for i in range(int(f)):
                index.append("critère{}".format(i + 1))
                columns.append("critère{}".format(i + 1))
            df = pd.DataFrame(data=b, index=index, columns=columns)
            print(df)
            arr = df.to_numpy()
            global c
            c = []
            for i in range(len(df)):
                c.append(np.prod(arr[i].astype(float)))

            df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=c, index=range(int(f)), columns=["hi"])
            print(df2)

        # Label(win, text="Enter matrix :", font=('arial', 10, 'bold'),
        #     bg="bisque2").place(x=20, y=20)

        x2 = 0
        y2 = 0

        rows = int(f)
        cols = int(f)
        global df2, df, c
        x = np.array(['1.1', '2.2', '3.3'])

        for i in range(rows):
    # append an empty list to your two arrays
    # so you can append to those later
            text_var.append([])
            entries.append([])
            for j in range(cols):
                # append your StringVar and Entry
                text_var[i].append(StringVar())
                entries[i].append(Entry(win, textvariable=text_var[i][j], width=5))
                entries[i][j].place(x=80 + x2, y=30 + y2)
                x2 += 40

            y2 += 30
            x2 = 0

        button = Button(wrapper1, text="Submit", bg='bisque3', width=15, command=get_mat)
        button.place(x=300, y=80)


        my_label = Label(wrapper3, text="Lamda Max:", width=24, font=("bold", 10))
        my_label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20, padx=5)
        my_entry = Entry(wrapper3)
        my_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=20, padx=5)
        # my_entry.insert(0,lamba)
        my_label1 = Label(wrapper3, text="Indice de Coherence (CI):", width=24, font=("bold", 10))
        my_label1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=20, padx=5)

        my_entry1 = Entry(wrapper3)
        my_entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=20, padx=5)

        my_label2 = Label(wrapper3, text="Indice de Racio (IC):", width=24, font=("bold", 10))
        my_label2.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20, padx=5)

        my_entry2 = Entry(wrapper3)
        my_entry2.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=20, padx=5)

        def calcule():
            global f

            df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=c, index=range(int(f)))

            df3 = pow(df2, 1 / int(f))
            print("df3 is ")
            print(df3)

            # Somme
            Somme = df3.sum()
            print("la somme est ")
            print(Somme)

            # weights
            B = df3 / Somme
            print(" La matrice des Poids:")
            print(B)

            # verify if somme of B is 1 , if it is then we are on the right road
            Somm = B.sum()
            print(Somm)

            # consistency check
            print("A3")
            C = np.dot(df, B)
            print(C)

            # consistency check
            print("A4")
            D = C / B
            print(D)
            # global lamba
            # Consistency Index
            # lambda
            lamba = np.mean(D)
            print("the average is ")
            print(lamba.to_string())
            my_entry.insert(0, lamba.to_string(index=False))

            # n = float(n)
            CI = (lamba - float(f)) / (float(f) - 1)
            print("The consistency Index  is")
            print(CI.to_string())
            my_entry1.insert(0, CI.to_string(index=False))
            # consistency ratio

            if int(f) == 3:
                RI = 0.52
            elif int(f) == 4:
                RI = 0.89
            elif int(f) == 5:
                RI = 1.11
            elif int(f) == 6:
                RI = 1.25
            elif int(f) == 7:
                RI = 1.35
            elif int(f) == 8:
                RI = 1.4
            elif int(f) == 9:
                RI = 1.45
            elif int(f) == 10:
                RI = 1.49
            print("THE RATIO IS :")
            print(RI)
            CR = float(CI / RI)
            my_entry2.insert(0, CR)
            if CR < 0.1:
                print("Congratulations ,Your criterias are consistent to go ahead \nThe value of consistency ratio is ",
                      CR,
                      "which is less han 0.1 ")
            else:
                print("you need to re-fill the matrix", CR)

        button = Button(wrapper3, text="calcule", bg='bisque3', width=15, command=calcule)
        button.place(x=500, y=100)
        a = IntVar()

        win.mainloop()
    window.mainloop()


be()
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Could you add the code you've tried?

Comment: If you just type ```1/7``` or use ```return 1/7``` in a function, it will work.

Comment: i added the code , it's a matrix that you fill in with different numbers but , fractions numbers doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Python actually has a built-in module just for this, which also has support for arbitrary-precision arithmetic and conversion to native floats.

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> frac = Fraction("1/7")
>>> float(fract)
0.14285714285714285
```

Easy to use, and works out-of-the-box. You can also convert it to an integer ratio, in case you want more accuracy than a native float can provide:

```
>>> frac.as_integer_ratio()
(1, 7)
```

The reason why `float("1/7")` doesn't work is because it's not a valid representation of an actual float: it's an integer ratio. Fractions, however, which provides native conversion to-and-from floats, does.

Comment: i tried Fraction but it doesn't work , thank you